# How to use Gtk.Button.clicked()? Wrong Number of arguments supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to build a graphical interface with python in GTK+/Pygobject, but i am having some trouble. Mainly with events.

What do i need? To execute a simple function whenever a button is clicked.
Sample code:

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
    [...]
    button = Gtk.Button()
    icon = Gio.ThemedIcon(name="system-shutdown-symbolic")
    image = Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(icon, Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)
    button.add(image)
    button.clicked(self.on_button_clicked())
    hb.pack_end(button)
    [...]


def on_button_clicked(self):
    print("Hello World")
```

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 7, in 
>       executa = igrafica.Window()
>     File "[...]/igrafica.py", line 23, in **init**
>       button.clicked(self.on_button_clicked())
>   TypeError: clicked() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

It seemed quite obvious what **button.clicked()** should do, but its traceback talks about wrong numbers of arguments, and i can't find out what the problem is from this [documentation i found](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gtk_3.0/classes/Button.html#clicked). What am i doing wrong?

PS: Is there any official not "too-much-hardcore-for-newbies" documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem obvious what the `clicked` signal should do, but you're misunderstanding the syntax for connecting a signal handler. Normally that would raise a more intuitive error, but in this case there's also a `clicked()` method on `Gtk.Button` that you are inadvertently calling. (That method is part of very old but not-yet-deprecated API, and fires a fake `clicked` signal.)

Do this:

```
button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
```

(remember not to put `()` after `self.on_button_clicked`, as eduffy pointed out, because you're not calling the method, but passing it as a parameter to another method.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 button.clicked(self.on_button_clicked())
```

you are calling `on_button_clicked` right here.  remove the `()` to simply reference the method:

```
 button.clicked(self.on_button_clicked)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it gave the exact same error: button.clicked(self.on_button_clicked)
TypeError: clicked() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)